# how to detect incoming Skype/Viber call

Tags: android, call, skype, viber

I am developing a music app and for that I need to detect incoming calls (Phone, Skype, Viber etc) in order to stop the playing song. I can detect GSM calls using PhoneState listener. Is there any way to detect data/VoIP (Skype, Viber) calls?

Comment: Check the solution here.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22904514/call-detection-for-skype-in-android

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You shouldn't need to detect anything so specific, but rather manage audio focus correctly. Please see this guide on how to do that: https://developer.android.com/training/managing-audio/audio-focus.html

Comment: Thanks, I want to know whenever phone rings by Skype or Viber call. for which stream should I request?  STREAM_ALARM, STREAM_DTMF, STREAM_MUSIC,STREAM_NOTIFICATION, STREAM_RING, STREAM_SYSTEM, STREAM_VOICE_CALL

Comment: Seems like `STREAM_RING` and `STREAM_VOICE_CALL` sound like good candidates. Try them out and see what happens. You can probably request more than one stream I would think.

Comment: @Karakuri Hi karakuri, do you get solution for detect incomming/outgoing calls for Skype.

Comment: No. I don't see how you could possibly do that.