# How to detect end call event in skype call

Tags: android, skype

I have integrated Skype call in my android application. What I wanted to do now is - to catch call end event. I know Skype doesn't provide API calling it just some URI for calling which I am using for calling. How can I detect the call end because when I press the end call button it get back to the Skype activity.I want it to go back to my application activity.

Is there is any workaround to achieve that?because I don't think of any.

Comment: A workaround would be to change the way the app works so it doesn't wait for a call end.

Comment: This could be a potential solution for your query.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22904514/call-detection-for-skype-in-android